# JWT + Swagger on Dotnet Core

Tags: .net-core, swagger

[I'm aware that you can configure swagger to provide a UI element to place a JWT](https://ppolyzos.com/2017/10/30/add-jwt-bearer-authorization-to-swagger-and-asp-net-core/). (Resulting in something like the following):

[image: Authorize button on Swagger UI]

However, my preference (for development) is to auto-generate and auto provide a JWT for Swagger UI Access. I understand the security implications. I'll deal with this in some other way, but my question is simply:

**How do I provide a key to Swagger through code?** Effectively, pre-fill in the following text box or more directly, just auto include a *valid* `Bearer` token header for each REST request coming from the Swagger UI.

[image: Fill-in Target in swagger]

Comment: Perhaps I need to use oAuth to loosely achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

We've done something like this in the past:

```
 config
   .EnableSwagger(c => {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", 
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"]);
                    AddXmlComments(c);
                  })
   .EnableSwaggerUi(c => c.InjectJavaScript(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), 
        "<<your namespace and file location>>.index.js"));
```

Then index.js would be something like this:

```
$("#input_apiKey").change(function () {
    setHeader($("#input_apiKey").val());
});

$(function () {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "<<url for getting your auth token>>",
        type: "GET",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
    });

    request.done(function (res) {
        setHeader(res.Header);
        $('#input_apiKey')[0].value = res.Header;
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Authorization Failed: " + textStatus);
    });

    $("#input_apiKey").attr("title", "Enter Header value from user service");
    $("#input_apiKey").attr("placeholder", "<<token header name>>");
})

function setHeader(key) {
    swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.remove("api_key");
    swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.remove("key");
    swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("<<token header name>>", key, "header"));
}
```